# Regex: Match a malformed date

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to grab the date (without time) from the following OCR'd strings:

```
04.10.2015, in USD
04.10.20 15, in EUR
04,1 0.2015, in XYZ
1 1. 10.2 01 5, in XYZ
0 1.11.201 5 12:30
1 1,0 3, 2 0 1 5 1 2:3 0
```

With the following expression I can catch the dates, but I can't skip the "12" hours:

```
([\d\s]{2,}(?:\.|,)[\d\s]{2,}(?:\.|,)[\d\s]{4,})
```

How can I make it work? In plain English, how can I make the last part stop once it has found 4 digits in a mix of digits and spaces/tabs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By catching the first 8 digits on a line, you will get your date.

- `\D` is any non-digit charater
- `\d` is a digit character
- `(?:...)` is a group that will be ignored
- `^\D*` is used to ignore the beginning of the line until we get a digit

We match 8 times a digits followed by any non-numerics characters, starting with first digit found.

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'^\D*((?:\d\D*?){8})', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"""04.10.2015, in USD
    04.10.20 15, in EUR
    04,1 0.2015, in XYZ
    1 1. 10.2 01 5, in XYZ
    0 1.11.201 5 12:30
    1 1,0 3, 2 0 1 5 1 2:3 0
"""

print re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Have a test over here: https://regex101.com/r/eQ8zJ9/4

You can then filter out any non digits to get the date:

```
from datetime import datetime

for s in re.findall(p, test_str):
    digits = re.sub(ur'\D', '', s)
    print datetime.strptime(digits, '%d%m%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with:

```
((?:\d\s*){2})[,.-]((?:\s*\d\s*){2})[,.-]((?:\s*\d){4})
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eQ8zJ9/3)

which is not restricted by beginning of a line. Also it match is there is one of choosen delimiters beetwen numbers, like `,`, `.` or `-`. As there could be more 8-digits chaotic number sequences in such formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is nice and short, but *if* the delimiters are of importance:

```
((?:(?:\d\s*){2}[.,]\s*){2}(?:\d\s*?){4})
```

The key being:

```
(?:\d\s*?){}
```

To capture  digits with optional, but non-greedy, whitespace in-between.

---

I also took the liberty to shorten `(?:\.|,)` to `[.,]`.